# 8 бит это 1 байт, а как измеряются сами биты?

Tags: битовые-операции, информатика

Как образовались биты? С помощью чего изначально они получены?

Comment: 8 бит это 1 октет, а 1 байт совсем не обязательно 8 бит

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82

Answer (score 2):

Бит - хранит одно из двух значений - 0 или 1. Образовались они из электросхем: 1 - есть заряд или напряжение, 0 - нет заряда или напряжения. Эти состояния атомарны и не подлежат дальнейшему разбиению.

Comment: Вообще Клод Шеннон придумал термин "бит" в 1948 еще до электросхем, как мы их сейчас понимаем и это математическое понятие. Его использование в электронных машинах - это уже прикладное применение теории информации.

Comment: Математически можно и к Блю отсылку сделать в XIX век, наверняка кто-то и раньше работал, но все-таки в контексте вопроса мне кажется правильнее рассматривать бит с инженерной точки зрения, а за исключением ранних семафоров (где такой термин кажется даже не использовался), биты связаны именно с электросхемами.

Comment: Скорее все таки общая теория информации. Машину можно и механическую сделать (ее такую и делали даже) и на ней так же был бит, как минимальная единица информации.

Comment: ...плюс на физическом уровне одна ячейка может запросто хранить несколько бит разом (см. MLC), тогда понятие бита становится чисто абстрактным.

Comment: Сейчас да, но если бы наши технологии были доступны в середине прошлого века мы скорее всего имели бы другое развитие компьютерной техники и другие термины. Если прорыв в области квантовых вычислений произойдет и мы получим в руки квантовые спец-функции, то произойдет качественный рывок даже не в компьютерной области, а научно-техническом прогрессе, сопоставимый с массовым использованием электричества или двигателей внутреннего сгорания. Это приведет к совершенно другой терминологии. Бит все-таки терминология прошлого века и он вошел в историю именно как состояние в электрических схемах.

Comment: А вот такой например стандарт `Напряжение от -25В до -3В - логическая "1", Напряжение от +3В до +25В - логический "0"` не вяжется с Вашим определением 0 - нет напряжения, 1 - есть

Comment: Это вопрос интерпретации и удобства реализации. Порядок отсчета бит в байте тоже может быть прямой или обратный, старший байт может быть расположен слева или справа. Вы заметили, что мы не обозначаем состояния бита 1 и -1? А ведь было бы логично, удобно и совместимо с тренарной логикой? Все-таки изначально в транзисторах и диодах напряжение либо было, либо нет. Поэтому 1 и 0. По мере усложнения схем, появлялись вариации напряжения.

Comment: @cheops, даже в электрических схемах бит - это не два состояния. Абстрактным он стал уже тогда, когда транзисторы начали упаковывать в интегральные схемы.